# We see it in our everyday lives!

Tags: riddle, word

I just realized that I kept on finding something wherever I go.

In my bathroom, my fridge, the map, outside, with the clouds. I see it everywhere!

Can you tell what it is?

**H1:**

> The word is short, and is very common. All around the world, it seems.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Is this a puzzle you created yourself? If not, please add a source (such as a link). We have an attribution policy here and unsourced puzzles will be closed and perhaps deleted.

Comment: @bobble Yep, this is an original riddle I thought of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to

> Water

In my bathroom, my fridge, the map, outside, with the clouds.

> Bathroom - from the taps and in the toilet
>  Fridge - ice or condensation
>  The map - water in the form of lakes and rivers is represented by a blue colour.
>  Outside - after it rains, puddles, etc
>  With the clouds - Clouds are water vapour