# I unlocked an item!

Tags: riddle, word

I came up to someone and they gave me some clues:

> It's fast, but can't run. It gets me ready for life. Everyone can have it. It is sold everywhere. It was here since Day 1.

So I went to find it, and just a bit of time later, I unlocked it. What is this item?

**H1:**

> It's a real thing, and not liquid.

**H2:**

> Just like [water](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107440/we-see-it-in-our-everyday-lives), you could see it anywhere.

Comment: Hi Mark! I see you've been adding hints pretty quickly here. Remember that it's the weekend, and that this is an international community. If your puzzle isn't solved in an hour you don't necessarily need to give hints - just wait for people to have time to look at it and/or to wake up.

Comment: I was just offering information. Also note that once you add a hint, you can't remove it *effectively* - it's in the public revision history. Something to consider for future puzzles/hints. Happy Puzzling!

Comment: Hello @Mark Giraffe. Welcome to the PSE. Hopefully you will find this site interesting and enjoyable. I think in addition to bobble's good suggestions please note that your puzzle does raise some questions about "unlocking" and Day 1. How would you define it? Big Bang? Start of the solar system? The accepted answer implies the begining of planets perhaps? I think because of these questions you might be seeing many comments and DVs. Please consider this for your next puzzle and have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

> Food

It's fast, but can't run.

> This is a reference to [fast food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_food)

It gets me ready for life.

> Food gives you the necessary energy for everyday life.

Everyone can have it. It is sold everywhere.

> Food is sold ubiquitously

It was here since Day 1.

> Since beings have needed energy from outside sources, food has been available

So I went to find it, and just a bit of time later, I unlocked it

> As explained by OP, buying food equates to "unlocking" it.

**Alternative Answer**

> Light

It's fast, but can't run.

> Light doesn't run but it travels fast (the fastest thing there is)

It gets me ready for life.

> Light (especially sunlight) in the morning gets you ready to start your day.

Everyone can have it. It is sold everywhere.

> Lightbulbs, matches, candles, torches are sold ubiquitously.

It was here since Day 1.

> Light has been around since the dawn of time.

So I went to find it, and just a bit of time later, I unlocked it.

> You unlocked your front door and light came flooding in.

Comment: But do you "unlock" food? - Also, it's not always fast.  When its fast, it wasn't here since Day 1.  If it was "can be fast", then I'd agree with everything you say, but would still wonder about the "unlock" part.

Comment: @CryptoFool You make a good point, I've changed my answer given your comment.

Comment: I think your way to allow light to be unlocked is a stretch.

Comment: Yep, it's originally food. Though that concept of light is pretty amazing. Congrats!

Comment: Reasons why it is "food": Fast food, food gives us energy to get ready for life, Everyone can have it, it is sold everywhere. When the first human was created (Adam), there already is food. What do I mean by unlocking? I got to a store and bought it.

Comment: Why is buying food "unlocking" it?  That doesn't make any sense to me.  You didn't unlock the food.  The food might have been locked up in the store, but then it was the store that was unlocked, not the food.  If "Food" is the right answer, then you should have left off the unlocking part.  Given its importance in the question (its in the title), I don't buy it.  You don't unlock food....and you don't unlock light either.

Answer (score 0):

My answer:

> Crops

Reasoning:

> This might not seem obvious at first glance, but the fact of Day 1 makes me think of games. So, what game has a kind of life like everyday life, is online (because of the everyone can have it fact), and has unlocking stuff? Minecraft. So, since crops grow fast IRL time compared to the easily programmed time in Minecraft, and the marketplace feel that makes it easily sold anywhere, I'm pretty sure this is the answer. The unlocking part means unlocking a chest to get those crops.

Comment: Good guess, but does it have to be about games? Not really, but good answer you got.

Answer (score -1):

You are AIR.

> It is fast but cannot run.

Under the right weather conditions the air moves fast.

> It gets me ready for life.

The pregnant mother breathes air and supplies the unborn baby with oxygen through the blood.

> Everyone can have it.

Air is available to all.

> It is sold everywhere.

Compressed air is sold to fill the tires of vehicles and many types of air is sold in storage cylinders.

> I was here since Day 1.

The air was in earth's atmosphere since time immemorial.

> I unlocked an item.

I unlocked my doors and windows and fresh air rushed in.

Comment: I have the same problem here as with the prior answer.  What does it mean to unlock air?  I also think air being fast is a stretch.  With that argument, almost anything can be fast.  Even when we have really high winds, like with tornados, we don't say.."wow, the air is fast".  Rather, air can be strong, when talking about winds.

Comment: Ah yes, air. Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: but you don't unlock air.  Unlocking doors and windows isn't unlocking air.  There's air already in the room.